# Translating a function integrating another function from BASIC into Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

The book [Calculus and Pizza](http://www.abebooks.com/products/isbn/9780471269878/11373725503) by Clifford Pickover has a few code examples here and there, all written in some dialect of BASIC.

I wrote a Python version of the code example covering integration. His BASIC example goes like:

```
10 REM Integration
20 DEF FNY(X) = X*X*X
30 A = 0
40 B = 1
50 N = 10
55 R = 0
60 H = (B-A)/N
70 FOR X = A TO B - H/2 STEP H
80     R = R + FNY(X)
90 NEXT X
100 R = R * H
110 PRINT *INTEGRATION ESTIMATE*: R
```

I changed a few things here and there, allowing the user to specify the interval over which to take the integral, specify the function to be integrated as a lambda, and so forth. I knew right off the bat that the for loop wouldn't work as I have written it below. I'm just wondering if there's some direct or idiomatic translation of the BASIC for to a Python for.

```
def simpleintegration():
    f = eval(input("specify the function as a lambda\n:%"))
    a = int(input("take the integral from x = a = ...\n:%"))
    b = int(input("to x = b = ...\n:%"))
    n = 10
    r = 0
    h = (b-a)/n
    for x in range(a,b-h/2,h):
        r = r + f(x)
    r = r * h
    print(r)
```

Comment: In my understanding, I take python as a NEW BASIC with immense power and clarity. The translation would be trivial to do by hand( if you are looking for translator, don't..that's what I mean).

Answer (score 1):

Your translation isn't far off.  The only difference between the `for` loop in other languages and Python's "loop-over-a-range" pattern is that the "stop" value is usually *inclusive* in other languages, but is *exclusive* in Python.

Thus, in most other languages, a loop including `a` and `b` looks like

```
for i = a to b step c
    ' Do stuff
next i
```

In Python, it would be

```
for i in range(a, b + 1, c):
    # Do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

The formula is computing the Riemann sums using the values at the left end of the subdivision intervals. Thus the last used value for `X` should be `B-H`.

Due to floating point errors, stepping from `A` by `H` can give a last value that is off by some small amount, thus `B-H` is not a good bound (in the BASIC code) and `B-H/2` is used to stop before `X` reaches `B`.

The Python code should work in the presented form for the same reasons, since the bound `B-H/2` is unreachable, thus the range should stop with `B-H` or a value close by.

Using a slight modification you can actually compute the trapezoidal approximation, where you initialize with `R=f(A)/2`, step `X` from `A+H` to including `B-H` adding `f(X)` to `R` and then finish by adding `f(B)/2` (which could already be done in the initialization). As before, the approximation of the integral is then `R*H`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below, just changing iteration of 'i' in for loop.

```
def simpleintegration():
    f = eval(input("specify the function as a lambda\n:%"))
    a = int(input("take the integral from x = a = ...\n:%"))
    b = int(input("to x = b = ...\n:%"))
    n = 10
    r = 0
    h = (b-a)/n
    for x = a to b-h/2 step h:
        r = r + f(x)
    r = r * h
    print(r)
```